# PHP GD Linear Dodge (Add)

Tags: gd

There is a function in PHP GD for Linear Dodge?

I wrote this function but I would like to know if exists a function like this in PHP GD

```
function imagecopyAdd (&$dst_im, &$src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < $src_w; $i++)
    {
        for($c = 0; $c < $src_h; $c++)
        {
            $rgb1 = imagecolorat($dst_im, ($i+$dst_x), ($c+$dst_y));
            $colors1 = imagecolorsforindex($dst_im, $rgb1);
            $rgb2 = imagecolorat($src_im, ($i+$src_x), ($c+$src_y));
            $colors2 = imagecolorsforindex($src_im, $rgb2);
            $r = $colors1["red"]+$colors2["red"];
            if($r > 255)
                $r = 255;
            $g = $colors1["green"]+$colors2["green"];
            if($g > 255)
                $g = 255;
            $b = $colors1["blue"]+$colors2["blue"];
            if($b > 255)
                $b = 255;
            $color = imagecolorallocate($dst_im, $r, $g, $b);
            imagesetpixel($dst_im, ($i+$dst_x), ($c+$dst_y), $color);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While my understanding of image manipulation at more than a visual level is fundamental at best, it seems like this may be built in to the options for [`imagefilter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php).

See this comment for the users' custom implementation that he says performs the exact same function as the built in option:

[It turns out PHP's Colorize is the equivalent of Photoshop's "Linear Dodge" layer filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php#91796).

Note these lines in his comment:

> // Usage: Just as `imagefilter()`, except with no filtertype.
> // `imagefilterhue(resource $image, int $red, int $green , int $blue)`
> `imagefilterhue($im,2,70,188);`
>
> // The equivalent with colorize, as tested in demo image:
> `imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 2, 70, 188);`

Where `imagefilterhue` is his custom implementation and `imagefilter` is the PHP GD function.

Comment: With that function it uses only 1 image and a RGB color, I want to use 2 images (like in this video: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n03EtVACY9c))